# Fatal error issue with woocommerce_thankyou hooked function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, payment-method

I need to print different messages based on payment method on the WooCommerce thank you page.

I am using the code below but it crashes my website and show me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_payment_method() on int...

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_add_content_thankyou' );
 
function bbloomer_add_content_thankyou($order) {
         if( 'bacs' == $order->get_payment_method() ) {

echo '<h2 class="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p class="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase!</p>';
         }
    else{
        echo '<h2 class="h2thanks">Get 100% off</h2><p class="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase!</p>';

    }
    
}
```

---

Someone who can tell me where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook you have access to the `$order_id`, not the `$order` object itself, hence the error.

To obtain the `$order` object you can use `wc_get_order( $order_id );`
where by means of the `$order_id` the `$order` object is obtained.

So you get:

```php
function bbloomer_add_content_thankyou( $order_id ) {    
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Is a WC_Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        // Payment method = bacs
        if( $order->get_payment_method() == 'bacs' ) {
            echo '<h2 class="h2thanks">Get 20% off</h2><p class="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<h2 class="h2thanks">Get 100% off</h2><p class="pthanks">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>Back4More</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase!</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_add_content_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```